# Ethereum sent to mistyped address

Tags: ether

I sent etherium to a one letter wrong address I typed  6 instead of a b amongst those letters from my mining account. I would like to know what can I do to recover those etheriums?

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately you probably can't, unless you find the owner of the address and ask them politely to return them to you. I know it's a bit late now, but... never type an address by hand, always copy and paste. If you're transcribing between two different machines, or two different media sources, find a way to transfer the address virtually. The minute you start transcribing by hand is the minute you start losing money.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. It's gone. Always, always copy and paste addresses. Then, verify it's the same address when pasted (check first few and last few characters), because there exists in the wild [malware that will surreptitiously change addresses on the clipboard to another address](https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-malware-changes-destination-wallet-to-steal-13-btc).

This is the process I follow, since I use multiple currencies:

1. Verify the source and destination wallets/exchanges/whatever are the same currency.
2. Copy and past the address
3. Verify the address is the same in the source and destination
4. Double-check 1-3
5. Submit

You're are dealing with (more-or-less) real money, so you have to be careful. For large amounts -- send a small test transfer and wait for it before continuing with the larger amount.

Comment: Just to add to this: Unlike Bitcoin, Ethereum addresses do not have any error checking features. All addresses (of the right length) are "valid", so one must be extra careful. There is no guarantee (and, in fact, odds are stacked against you) that someone has the private key corresponding to the address your ether were sent to.